# Why is my Code is no longer working after I moved Computers?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I wrote some code on another computer in python and I emailed the file to my new computer. Now, it no longer works. Below is the attached code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import *
from random import *

w,h = 1200,1200
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=w, height=h, bg='white')
canvas.pack()
colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'orange']
dict = {}
fontsizes = open('lab23.txt', 'r').read().split(" \n")
randY = 0
randX = 0
randColor = 0
print fontsizes
i,k = 0,0
while i < len(fontsizes)-1:
   key = fontsizes[i]
   i += 1
   val = int(fontsizes[i])
   i += 1
   dict[key] = val
print len(fontsizes)
while k < len(fontsizes)-1:
   if len(fontsizes[k]) > 2:
      randY = randint(100, 1100)
      randX = randint(100, 1100)
      randColor = randint(0, 4)
      f = ('Times', dict[fontsizes[k]]) 
      canvas.create_text(randX, randY, text = fontsizes[k], font = f, fill = colors[randColor])
   k +=1
def space(evt):
   k = 0
   canvas.delete('all')
   while k < len(fontsizes)-1:
      if len(fontsizes[k]) > 2:
         randY = randint(100, 1100)
         randX = randint(100, 1100)
         randColor = randint(0, 4)
         f = ('Times', dict[fontsizes[k]]) 
         canvas.create_text(randX, randY, text = fontsizes[k], font = f, fill = colors[randColor])
      k +=1
root.bind('<space>',space)

root.mainloop()
```

when I run the code, I get the error message:

```
File "Lab24.py", line 19
    print fontsizes
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Looks like the other computer is using python 3, where `print` was changed to be a function. Change to `print(fontsizes)`.

Comment: While you're at it, just use `2to3 -w your_source_file.py` to update all such python 2/3 differences into their Python3 equivalents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first computer was probably running python. The 2nd computer is probably running python3 which (I believe) requires the syntax to be `print(fontsizes)`

On line 19 of your program you use `print fontsizes`

This will need to be change in all the places you print like that. I would recommend using the parathese "()" because (I believe) it works on all versions of python.

Comment: If this solved your question please mark it as the answer.